# Understanding Triage by case example

Tags: support, review-queues, triage

I have been exposed to Review Queues for some time and would like to contribute to helping by having a clearer idea on how to flag questions appropriately by looking at some case studies.  I have read the answer to the question: [Is there a guide for the Triage queue?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue), but would like a little more clarity on some specific recurring type of questions,

**1. Users asking to debug their code.**

I see quite a few questions coming under this category, with titles,

> "I am trying to.... but it does not work, how do I...?"

and the question that follows is a long piece of code with no apparent attempt of any research on the issue. 
In this case, would one flag the question as,

- a. Looks Ok
- b. Needs Editing
- c. Unsalvageable -> if so which sub-category?
- d. Skip it.

I tend to go for (b), is this correct?

**2. Vague/Broad/Unclear questions.**

There are some questions with poor/no research,

- someone who is [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59425566/how-can-i-install-kivy-on-windows) for help to install software on Windows, with no attempt to list any of the issues they are facing.
- a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/24908409) to solve a problem but remains vague with multiple question beings asked, which reflects little to no attempt to formulate a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

In this case, one should flag it as

a. Looks Ok - b. Needs Editing - c. Unsalvageable -> Needs details / Needs Focus - d. Skip it.

I would go with (c) -> Needs more details.

Would the above flags be acceptable?

Comment: Why would to take "b" for the first example when the description of the options is **"Requires Editing for questions that you can make clear and answerable by editing"**. Can you edit debug attempts into the question?

Comment: No, that's true, but I have a feeling that with a better title, the question could have an answer.  However, I am unsure and hence this question.

Comment: *"the question could have an answer."* ... that's not necessarily the question we should ask here. We want to build a repository of Q&As and when the question is unfit for that format, then it doesn't matter if it could have an answer or not. So when the question is unhelpful for future readers, then still vote to close the question.

Comment: that's crystal clear @Tom, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Your second flag, yes. That is the acceptable response. The first one isn't, choosing "needs editing" should only be done if the question can be improved by anyone **without OP's help**. In this case, it is a bad question and should be downvoted/commented. But it is still a (salvageable) question, so "looks OK" would be a better response. Unless you know OP won't fix it, in that case flag as "Needs details or clarity".

Comment: Thanks. That''s interesting, it is acceptable to flag the 1st question as (a)- It looks ok‚ and simply downvote+comment in order to entice the OP to edit their question